# Is it true that the column vector $(x_1,x_2,0)^T\in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: notation, vectors

I just started reading about vectors. For the vector ${ \begin{bmatrix}{x_1} \\ {x_2} \\ {0}\end{bmatrix} }$ (where $x_1,x_2\neq0$) I know we have${ \begin{bmatrix}{x_1} \\ {x_2} \\ {0}\end{bmatrix} }\in \mathbb{R}^3$. But because the vector is on the xy-plane, I wonder is it correct to say ${ \begin{bmatrix}{x_1} \\ {x_2} \\ {0}\end{bmatrix} }\in \mathbb{R}^2$? and why?

Comment: No, it’s not true.

Comment: It is on the $xy$-plane, but it is also on an infinite number of other planes.

Comment: Just one thing to add: if this is part of a study of linear algebra, you'll find later on in your studies that having $(x_1, x_2, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or something similar will mess up the properties of the vector space you're considering (in this case, $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3, \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

The third coordinate is there.

It avoid confusion and makes it clear which space are you working on.